# php mysql select option

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems with my code.

I have a registration form which works fine apart form one area.  The select option the user should select 'Yes' or 'No' from the options and then it should insert this 'Yes' or 'No' into the mysql database.  Due to my code error it is not inserting anything.  can you help me as to where i am going wrong please.

registration page code has this html among the form

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<label>Member<span class="req">*</span></label>
<select name="member">
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
</form>
```

this is then posted to my php page which has this code

```
    <?php
    $member = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['member']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO members (member) " 
            . 

 "VALUES('$member')";
?>
```

obviously this is due to my lack of experience and is probably a really stupid mistake i have made but cannot see.  I have spent a few days trawling around trying to get the answer but without any success.

Many Thanks

Comment: Execute the query.

Comment: you should read more..

Comment: ...and use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements. You won't need to escape string anymore.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members (member) VALUES(?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['member']);//bind parameter to placeholder
return $stmt->execute() === true ? true : false;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have written the query but have not executed it.

Use `$mysqli->query($sql);` to run the query.

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO members (member) VALUES ('$member')";
    $mysqli->query($sql);`